# Clock frequency setting doesn't change simulation speed

Tags: emulation, avr, simulator, simavr

I'm trying to run the following AVR program on SimAVR:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main ()
{
    DDRB |= _BV(DDB5);

    for (;;)
    {
        PORTB ^= _BV(PB5);
        _delay_ms(2000);
    }
}
```

I've compiled it with `F_CPU=16000000`. The SimAVR runner is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "sim_avr.h"
#include "avr_ioport.h"
#include "sim_elf.h"

avr_t * avr = NULL;

static void* avr_run_thread(void * ignore)
{
    for (;;) {
        avr_run(avr);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void led_changed_hook(struct avr_irq_t* irq, uint32_t value, void* param)
{
    printf("led_changed_hook %d %d\n", irq->irq, value);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    elf_firmware_t f;
    elf_read_firmware("image.elf", &f);
    f.frequency = 16e6;

    const char *mmcu = "atmega328p";
    avr = avr_make_mcu_by_name(mmcu);
    if (!avr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: AVR '%s' not known\n", argv[0], mmcu);
        exit(1);
    }
    avr_init(avr);
    avr_load_firmware(avr, &f);

    avr_irq_register_notify(
        avr_io_getirq(avr, AVR_IOCTL_IOPORT_GETIRQ('B'), 5),
        led_changed_hook,
        NULL);

    pthread_t run;
    pthread_create(&run, NULL, avr_run_thread, NULL);

    for (;;) {}
}
```

The problem is that I see from the output of `led_changed_hook` that it runs at ~4x speed. Moreover, changing `f.frequency` doesn't seem to have any effect on the simulation speed whatsoever.

How do I ensure that SimAVR runs the simulation at the correct real-time speed?

Comment: Why should anything that mainly consists of a  constant delay in ms run faster when you bump up the CPU frequency?

Comment: I thought the `_delay_ms` macro expands to a busy-wait? For example, if I compile it with `F_CPU=800000` and then upload and run it on a real chip running at 16MHz, I do see the blinking happening at twice the speed.

Comment: @tofro: [this documentation page](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) is quite explicit that `_delay_ms` &c. are using busy-wait for a compile-time-computed number of cycles.

Comment: Yes, it does - So it was the very same binary? No Build in-between?

Comment: @tofro: I built the AVR program with `F_CPU=16e6`, and then I loaded the resulting `image.elf` into the SimAVR runner. Then I started playing around with the frequency setting _in SimAVR_, i.e. by changing `f.frequency`, and that doesn't seem to change the "blinking" speed.

Comment: @tofro: so just to clarify: `_delay_ms` is compiled into a busy-wait loop for a given number of cycles. I then load that program into the simulator, and I expect it to take the correct number of seconds when the clock frequency is the same, since if it is, then that many cycles should take 2 seconds.

Comment: The *simavr* manual implies that MCU type and frequency are being read from the binary. "*Microcontroller (MCU)  and  frequency  information  have  been  embedded  into  the  binary  and are therefore available in elf_firmware_t*"

Comment: @tofro: yes, but as you can see from the example program's source, I'm not injecting any extra metadata into the generated `.elf` file (since eventually I'll want to use this with programs that are compiled outside my control). This is why I have to explicitly pass `"atmega328p"` explicitly as the MCU type instead of reading it out from `image.elf`. Similarly, I am overriding `f.frequency` (which defaults to `0` since I don't have any metadata in my `image.elf`).

Comment: I'm not sure that *F_CPU=800000* **doesn't** leave a hint in the ELF file.

Comment: @tofro: first of all, I am trying this with `F_CPU=16e6`, the `8e6` setting was just for quick testing that the setting takes on the real MCU. Second, if I print `f.frequency` before setting it, it prints 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It turns out SimAVR doesn't support timing-accurate simulation of opcodes](https://github.com/buserror/simavr/issues/201#issuecomment-280616749) so the simulation time of running the busy-wait of `_delay_ms` to completion is completely unrelated to

- how long it would take on the real MCU
- the clock frequency of the simulated MCU

The correct solution is to use a timer interrupt, and then go to sleep on the MCU. The simulator will correctly simulate the timer counters and the sleep will suspend the simulation until the timer fires.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>

int main ()
{
    DDRB |= _BV(DDB5);

    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;
    TCNT1  = 0;
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);

    sei();

    /* Set TIMER1 to 0.5 Hz */
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
    OCR1A   = 31248;
    TCCR1B |= ((1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10));

    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_IDLE);
    sleep_enable();
    for (;;)
    {
        sleep_mode();
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
    PORTB ^= _BV(PB5);
}
```